# how do i make light mode stay when switching pages?

Tags: javascript, html, css, lightmode

so my website is dark mode by default and i have added a light mode button to make the website light
and i want the light mode to stay when switching pages, how can i make the light mode stay when switching pages.
JS

```
//light mode for home page
function lightMode() {


    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("light-mode");

    var buttonText = document.getElementById('lightModeButton');
    if (buttonText.innerHTML === "Light") {
        buttonText.innerHTML = "Dark";

    }

    else {
        buttonText.innerHTML = "Light"
    }



    var footerLight = document.getElementById('footer');
    footerLight.classList.toggle("footer-color");
    footerLight.classList.toggle("footer-color a");




}

// light mode function for my information page

function lightModeInformation() {

    var textInfo = [document.getElementById('textInformation'), document.getElementById('textInformation2'), document.getElementById('h1Information')];
    textInfo[0].classList.toggle("text-when-light");
    textInfo[1].classList.toggle("text-when-light");
    textInfo[2].classList.toggle("text-when-light");

    var element = document.body;
    element.classList.toggle("light-mode");

    var buttonText = document.getElementById('lightModeButton');
    if (buttonText.innerHTML === "Light") {
        buttonText.innerHTML = "Dark";

    }

    else {
        buttonText.innerHTML = "Light"
    }

    var footerLight = document.getElementById('footer');
    footerLight.classList.toggle("footer-color");
    footerLight.classList.toggle("footer-color a");


}
```

i tried using if statements but it didnt work

Comment: you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: could you give an example @Usama

Answer (score 2):

A good way to achieve this would be using something like `localStorage` or  `sessionStorage`. Session storage will be cleared when the user closes the tab/browser but `localStorage` will be persisted until manually cleared by the user.

You can do something like `localStorage.setItem('mode', 'dark')` or `localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light')` when the function is called to switch between light and dark mode, and then on page load you can check this `localStorage` value again and apply it.

Something along the lines of:

```
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  let mode = localStorage.getItem('mode')
  if (mode === 'light') {
      lightMode()
  }
});
```

You could of course have another check here as well for the user's preferred mode using this line

```
const prefersDarkMode = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme:dark)").matches; // Returns true or false
```

Some more information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest saving the information about whether a user uses light or dark mode in the `localStorage`. You can access this variable from the `localStorage` on each of your sites from the same domain. It also persists sessions, if you don't delete it manually.

e.g. set the mode like `localStorage.setItem('mode', 'light');`
and refer to it like `const mode = localStorage.getItem('mode');`

Check out the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Comment: I am not sure how to use localStorage since i am still new to web dev